# Div not confirming to grid. Defined an 8 column grid and elements are binding to 4 column. Susy

Tags: susy-compass, susy-sass, susy

My div is not matching up to my grid. It's an 8 container grid and when I tell the element to span(2), it acts as if the grid were 4. Is this because I'm not defining a global grid in $susy?

Some contextual code:

First I defined a container grid:

```
 #grid{
        @include container(8);
        gutter-width: 5%;
       }
```

Then I added it to the html:

```
<main id="grid">...</div>
```

Then I nested the div in css:

```
#object1{
    @extend %object;
    @include span(2);
    }
```

and added it to the html

```
<main id="grid">
   <div id="object1">a</div>
</main>
```

#### edit: fixed (must define context even in child elements. why is that? if i can set span according to any grid amount that i want, then what's the point of all this with-layout and context following hokey pokey? If span doesn't read context from the parent element then what the hell is the point of susy?)

[Here's the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaH3q.png)

Comment: The `container()` mixin takes a width as (optional) argument, *not* the number of columns – cf. [documentation](http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/settings/#container).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to pass the explicit context to every single container/span element *if you set it globally*. Susy (and any other Sass plugin) is not aware of the DOM, and so it is not aware that `#object1` is inside `#grid` which has been set to `8 columns`.

Every item needs context from somewhere. If you don't pass it in explicitly, Susy checks the global settings, which default to `4 columns`. If you change the global setting to `8`, then you don't need to pass context into your mixins. The `with-layout` mixin is just one way to change the global setting temporarily, for a block of nested code.

```
.default {
  @include span(2); // uses global default of 4
}

$susy: layout(8);

.custom {
  @include span(2); // uses global setting of 8

  @include with-layout(4) {
    @include span(2); // uses temporary setting of 4
  }

  @include span(2); // uses global setting of 8 again
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eric, you rock! I remember reading about the DOM. I guess it didn't sink it. I'm a newb developer. I also appreciate you contextualizing with-layout. Great work you've done with this project of yours. It is exemplary.